# CIM vs WMI returning different information

Tags: powershell, wmi, cim

I was trying to take advantage of CIM's built-in parallel processing to get information about all the installed printers against a given subnet of computers. The script works faster than my WMI variation, but doesn't return the same information and doesn't always return as much as the `Get-WmiObject` call.

EDIT: The information the script drops is information about entire computers.

Here's the CIM version:

```
$Computer = Get-Content -Path c:\Scripts\input.txt  

$Objects = foreach ($ComputerName in $Computer) {
    # New CIM Instance 
    Write-Host Collecting information on $ComputerName 
    $Cim = New-CimSession -ComputerName $ComputerName 

    # Collect Printer Info
    Get-CimInstance -CimSession $Cim -Class Win32_printer -Property deviceid, drivername, portname, systemName

    # Define Hashtable properties 
    $ObjectProperties = @{
        SystemName = $Cim.systemName
        DeviceID   = $Cim.deviceid
        DriverName = $Cim.drivername
        PortName   = $Cim.portname
    }

    # Create new object
    New-Object PSObject -Property $ObjectProperties        
}

# Export Results 
$Objects | Select DeviceID, DriverName, PortName, SystemName |
    Export-Csv - NoTypeInformation -Path c:\Scripts\output.csv
```

Here's the WMI version:

```
$results = @()
$Computer = Get-Content -Path c:\Scripts\input.txt

# Check each computer in the list 
foreach ($ComputerName in $Computer) {
    $results += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_printer -cn $ComputerName |
                Select deviceid, drivername, portname, systemName
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
}

# Export to CSV file
$Results | Select DeviceID, DriverName, PortName, SystemName |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path c:\Scripts\output.csv
```

We sometimes need to run this script against multiple subnets. I moved to the CIM sessions because it reduced the total run of the script to consistently under 5 minutes, but if it's not going to return all of the information, it might be better to wait.

Does anyone have any idea on how to prevent CIM from dropping information?

It should be noted that WinRM is not enabled by default on these machines and the script has to force enable CIMs with the following command.

```
& "c:\Scripts\SnIPT\psexec.exe" \\$ComputerName -s -d -n 5 winrm.cmd quickconfig -q -force
```

Comment: What information are you missing? Missing objects from some coputers or did CIM ignore a single property like DriveName?

Comment: Your first troubleshooting step should be to make the 2 scripts as similar as possible. For instance, both `Get-WmiObject` and `Get-CimInstance` have a parameter `-ComputerName`, so there's no need to open a CIM session first. Also, one script is collecting the output of the loop in a variable, while the other is appending to an array. Do the former in both cases, because it provides significantly better performance. One script is building custom objects while the other is just using `Select-Object`. Do the latter in both cases.

Comment: As for the actual differences in the results of both scripts: are entire records missing, the values of some property, or do you get differing values for the same systems from both scripts? Do the systems where the differences occur have something in common (operating system, PowerShell version, installed software, firewall settings, ...)?

Comment: Thank you, I"ll clean that up and make them more similar.

Records for multiple computers are missing, but as you and @FrodeF it might be due to different versions of windows. I'm running this against possibly thousands of machines (not all at once, but over time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same WMI-class should return the same data (however CIM-cmdlets convert dates ++). Since you haven't explained what's different I'd guess it's missing output for certain computers. Usually this is because the target computer is missing Windows Management Framework 3.0 or later (think PS 3.0+) which is required for CIM. If that's the case, it should generate an error that you can catch and use to use DCOM (same as WMI) as a fallback. Ex:

```
$Computer = Get-Content -Path c:\Scripts\input.txt  

$DCOM = New-CimSessionOption -Protocol Dcom    

$Objects = ForEach($ComputerName in $Computer)
{
    #New Cim Instance with fallback to DCOM 
    Write-Host Collecting information on $ComputerName 

    $Cim = $null
    try {
        $Cim = New-CimSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -ErrorAction Stop
    } catch [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimException] {
        #CIM not available on target (requires WMF 3.0+). Using DCOM (used by WMI)
        try { $Cim = New-CimSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -SessionOption $DCOM -ErrorAction Stop }
        catch { Write-Host $_.Exception.Message }
    }

    #Collect Printer Info
    Get-CimInstance -CimSession $Cim -Class Win32_printer -Property DeviceID, DriverName, PortName, SystemName

    #Best practice to store the original object.
    #No need to create a new one with a few properties when you do it during export anyways.
    #If you really need it, add "| Select-Object -Property DeviceID, DriverName, PortName, SystemName" to the previous line

}

#Export Results 
$Objects | Select-Object -Property DeviceID, DriverName, PortName, SystemName |  Export-Csv - NoTypeInformation -Path c:\Scripts\output.csv
```

Comment: Thanks. Fixed. Forgot a line

Comment: It's probably the Windows Management Framework. Across the various networks there are thousands of machines so it makes sense that they wouldn't all have that.